# Colorama won't output given color

Tags: python

I've been working with colorama and I've seen some answers on the web saying that colorama only works in the terminal. I've opened my python file with the launcher as an exe and it's always worked perfectly fine. However this time, it's changed. When I run this snippet in VSCode:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style

green = Fore.GREEN
print(f'{green}This is a test')
```

Everything runs great and my output is green. But when I run my file with the python launcher, I get this instead: `[32mThis is a test`

I know that colorama still works with the launcher because I've used it a couple days ago. And by launcher, I apologize for the ignorance, you know how when you right click on a file and it says open with "Python". I called that the launcher. Someone from StackOverflow said to ask my question here about color codes. Any insight at all would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is not working in the **IDLE Shell** when you start it by the Integrated Development and Learning Environment (IDLE).

On Windows use PowerShell instead and following code saved e.g. in desktop folder `new-2.py`:

```python
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

# by Colorama’s constant shorthand for ANSI escape sequences:
# -----------------------------------------------------------
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print('\033[31m' + 'some red text')
print('\033[39m') # and reset to default color

# by manually printing ANSI sequences from your own code:
# -------------------------------------------------------
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')

# by using your code sample
# -------------------------
green = Fore.GREEN
print(f'{green}This is a test')
```

This is resulting in the output below:

[image]